# Affinity propagation clustering of radio signal strength data using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to cluster my datasets (radio signal strength from WiFi access points at a 2-D surface) using affinity propagation. I followed [this](https://www.toptal.com/machine-learning/clustering-algorithms) and [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation) links to grasp the basics of affinity propagation clustering. The sample code available at sklearn is as follows:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
# Generate sample data
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.5,
                            random_state=0)
# Compute Affinity Propagation
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-50).fit(X)
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_
```

The above code runs well. I want to modify it for my own datasets. My datasets are in the following form:

[image]

Here, each dot represent a grid point on the 2-D surface. And each grid point contains radio signal strength from various WiFi access points. I want to cluster the grid points according to the similarity on radio signal strength from WiFi access points. Can I do it using sklearn? Has any one done it using sklearn? Any links or sample code, please.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this question may be too broad - could you possibly make it more specific, for instance, "how can I input 2d location data into this code block", or something like that?  (I may be wrong about this, I'm not an expert on ML)

Comment: I solved it using [R](https://www.r-project.org/).

Comment: Cool!  In that case you should answer your own question, and then you can accept your answer in 2 days.